# jQuery order of execution using $.load() asynchronous problems (bootstrap modal)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I'm having an odd issue with jQuery order of operations.  The code below executes perfectly in ie9 & ie10.  In ie11, firefox, and chrome, it doesn't work at all.  It will execute and open the new window, but load() doesn't fire.  I can put an alert in the event chain and load() works in firefox and ie11...in chrome it still never runs load().

At first, I thought load's target simply hadn't been added to the DOM yet and that the pause created by the alert gave it time to be created.  I added a sleep timer in the exact same spot to test that theory--it didn't work, and it didn't matter how long the timer was set to.

Any thoughts on this problem would be helpful.  Thanks guys and gals!

```
    function openWindow(id, which, windowOptions) {
        $('<div>')
        .attr('id', 'GenericWindow')
        .addClass('modal hide fade')
        .html('<div class="modal-header"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button><h3 id="WindowHeader">Loading...</h3>'
        + '</div><div id="divWindowContent" class="modal-body">Content!</div><div id="WindowButtons" class="modal-footer"><input type="button" id="btnWindowCancel" value="Cancel" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" />'
        + '<input type="button" id="btnWindowSave" value="Save" class="btn btn-info" />')
        .modal({"keyboard":"true"})
        .on('hidden', function (e) {
            var src = $(e.target);
            if (!src.hasClass('popover-link')) {
                $('#GenericWindow').remove();
                clearErrors();
            }
        });
        if (!windowOptions) {
            //THIS IS THE ALERT.
            alert('huh');

            var link = '@Url.Action("replace", "Operations")'
            link = link.replace("replace", which);

            $('#divWindowContent').load(link, { id: id }, function (response, status, xhr) {
                if (status == "error") {
                    var msg = "Error loading details : ";
                    $('#divWindowContent').html(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            if (windowOptions.action) {
                var action = windowOptions.action;
                    var link = '@Url.Action("view", "controller", new { Area = "MvcMembership" })';
                if (!$.isNull(action.area))
                    link = link.replace("MvcMembership", action.area);
                else
                    link = link.replace("/MvcMembership", "");
                link = link.replace("view", action.view);
                link = link.replace("controller", action.controller);

                $('#divWindowContent').load(link, action.values, function (response, status, xhr) {
                    if (status == "error") {
                        var msg = "Error loading details : ";
                        $('#divWindowContent').html(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
                    }
                });
            }
            else {
                $('#divWindowContent').html(windowOptions.text);                    
            }
            $('#WindowHeader').html(windowOptions.title);
            if (windowOptions.hideButtons) {
                $('#WindowButtons').remove();
                $('#GenericWindow .close').remove();
            }
            $('#GenericWindow').css('width', windowOptions.width);
            $('#GenericWindow').css('height', windowOptions.height);
        }
    }
```

EDIT: I should note that if you are using a function to close any open modal on the page before opening a new modal, appendTo('body') does not work.  You must use the "create-a-variable" solution.  It's also worth noting that creating a variable is much, much faster, especially after the first modal open.

Comment: Updated the title to more accurately reflect the fact that the bootstrap modal is the source of the problem and to make it easier to find/reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The window that you create dynamically is not properly caught by the selector until you add it as an element in the page (for Chrome anyway).

To solve this issue you could either append the `GenericWindow` to the `body` and dismiss it when you close the window.

Or store the element in a variable and call your load on the variable.

Working examples with Chrome in jsfiddle :

Solution 1 :http://jsfiddle.net/4c3hu/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    openWindow('blerg', 'test', null);
});


function openWindow(id, which, windowOptions) {
        $('<div>')
        .attr('id', 'GenericWindow')
        .addClass('modal hide fade')
        .html('<div class="modal-header"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button><h3 id="WindowHeader">Loading...</h3>'
    + '</div><div id="divWindowContent" class="modal-body">Content!</div><div id="WindowButtons" class="modal-footer"><input type="button" id="btnWindowCancel" value="Cancel" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" />'
    + '<input type="button" id="btnWindowSave" value="Save" class="btn btn-info" />')
        .modal({"keyboard":"true"})
        .appendTo('body')
        .on('hidden', function (e) {
            var src = $(e.target);
            if (!src.hasClass('popover-link')) {
                $('#GenericWindow').remove();
                clearErrors();
            }
        });
        if (!windowOptions) {
            //THIS IS THE ALERT.
            console.log('huh');

            var link = '@Url.Action("replace", "Operations")'
            link = link.replace("replace", which)
            link = '/echo/html/'
            console.log(link);
            $('#divWindowContent').load(link, { id: id }, function (response, status, xhr) {
                console.log('after load');
                if (status == "error") {
                    var msg = "Error loading details : ";
                    $('#divWindowContent').html(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            if (windowOptions.action) {
                var action = windowOptions.action;
                var link = '@Url.Action("view", "controller", new { Area = "MvcMembership" })';
                if (!$.isNull(action.area))
                    link = link.replace("MvcMembership", action.area);
                else
                    link = link.replace("/MvcMembership", "");
                link = link.replace("view", action.view);
                link = link.replace("controller", action.controller);

                $('#divWindowContent').load(link, action.values, function (response, status, xhr) {
                    if (status == "error") {
                        var msg = "Error loading details : ";
                        $('#divWindowContent').html(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
                     }
                });
            }
            else {
                $('#divWindowContent').html(windowOptions.text);                    
            }
            $('#WindowHeader').html(windowOptions.title);
            if (windowOptions.hideButtons) {
                $('#WindowButtons').remove();
                $('#GenericWindow .close').remove();
            }
            $('#GenericWindow').css('width', windowOptions.width);
            $('#GenericWindow').css('height', windowOptions.height);
        }
    }
```

Solution 2 :http://jsfiddle.net/4c3hu/1/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    openWindow('blerg', 'test', null);
});


function openWindow(id, which, windowOptions) {
        var $elem = $('<div>')
        .attr('id', 'GenericWindow')
        .addClass('modal hide fade')
        .html('<div class="modal-header"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button><h3 id="WindowHeader">Loading...</h3>'
        + '</div><div id="divWindowContent" class="modal-body">Content!</div><div id="WindowButtons" class="modal-footer"><input type="button" id="btnWindowCancel" value="Cancel" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" />'
        + '<input type="button" id="btnWindowSave" value="Save" class="btn btn-info" />')
        .modal({"keyboard":"true"})
        .on('hidden', function (e) {
            var src = $(e.target);
            if (!src.hasClass('popover-link')) {
                $('#GenericWindow').remove();
                clearErrors();
            }
        });
        if (!windowOptions) {
            //THIS IS THE ALERT.
            console.log('huh');

            var link = '@Url.Action("replace", "Operations")'
            link = link.replace("replace", which)
            link = '/echo/html/'
            console.log(link);
            $elem.load(link, { id: id }, function (response, status, xhr) {
                console.log('after load');
                if (status == "error") {
                    var msg = "Error loading details : ";
                    $('#divWindowContent').html(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            if (windowOptions.action) {
                var action = windowOptions.action;
                var link = '@Url.Action("view", "controller", new { Area = "MvcMembership" })';
                if (!$.isNull(action.area))
                    link = link.replace("MvcMembership", action.area);
                else
                    link = link.replace("/MvcMembership", "");
                link = link.replace("view", action.view);
                link = link.replace("controller", action.controller);

                $elem.load(link, action.values, function (response, status, xhr) {
                    if (status == "error") {
                        var msg = "Error loading details : ";
                        $('#divWindowContent').html(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
                    }
                });
            }
            else {
                $('#divWindowContent').html(windowOptions.text);                    
            }
            $('#WindowHeader').html(windowOptions.title);
            if (windowOptions.hideButtons) {
                $('#WindowButtons').remove();
                $('#GenericWindow .close').remove();
            }
            $('#GenericWindow').css('width', windowOptions.width);
            $('#GenericWindow').css('height', windowOptions.height);
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, Yan!  This solution was perfect; appendTo('body') worked like a charm.  Hackish, but simple and elegant at the same time.  Love it.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is not with the `.load()` function, but with the way `.modal()` appends new elements to the DOM. It is not consistent across browers.

Additionally, jQuery's selectors only ever look through what's already appended to the DOM.

Here's a fiddle illustrating the issue:

http://jsfiddle.net/4NdNQ/

This will print `0, 1` in some browsers and `1, 1` in others.

What you want to do is to keep a reference to the parent and search through its children rather than all DOM elements. The fiddle below illustrates this, it will always find the contained `<div>` in any browser:

http://jsfiddle.net/4NdNQ/1/

Here's what makes the magic happen:

```
var container = $('<div>').html('<div id=myElementId></div>');
// container now only exists in the script stack, it's not present in the DOM
$("#myElementId"); // <- this selects nothing
container.find("#myElementId").load( /* parameters */); // <- this now works
```

---

ED: @YanBrunet's answer also explains the problem, but I'll leave this as an alternative way to tackle it - as it's a smaller change

Comment: Thank you!  I would have spent months trying to figure this out.  Your explanation of the problem was clearer, but I really like the simplicity of @YanBrunet's .appendTo('body') solution.  For the record, both solutions worked.  Upvoted your answer.